# Having problem to login after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

I just update to 12.04 from 11.10 and I get to the login screen w/o problems. When I enter my password the screen turns black and returns to the login screen half a second later.

There is a related question out there which was solved by creating more space on the disk but my disks (or rather partitions) are all below 30%.

I can log in as guest. I can also login at the cmd prompt (going to tty with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) with my normal user credentials. When logged in as guest I can also install programs using my normal account password.

There is the normal authentication error when I mistype my password so I'm also sure the password works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I actually figured this one out myself.
The problem was that I had installed 12.04 from CD but retained the old home partition. When I created my new user (with the same name as the old one) I got the correct home directory but wrong UID and GID. When I changed it to the correct values everything worked again!